# Elixir: decrement map item produces argument error

Tags: elixir

I came accros some behavior I wasn't expecting ... is it normal ?

```
Interactive Elixir (1.5.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> test = %{a: 0}
%{a: 0}
iex(2)> test.a
0
iex(3)> test.a - 1
-1
iex(4)> test.a -1
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.apply(%{a: 0}, :a, [-1])
```

Well, the workaround is quite simple. I just want to understand, why is it behaving so.

Comment: Yes, it is normal. It is parsed as `test.a(-1)` in this case and hence produces an error you got.

Comment: Interestingly, when you try it on a simple bound variable `a`, you get a more explicit error: `** (CompileError) iex:3: "a -1" looks like a function call but there is a variable named "a", please use explicit parentheses or even spaces`

Comment: Yet when I tried `1 -1` it isn't parsed like a function call ... :) Guess it means that no function can be named with digits only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test.a - 1
```

is considered as decrement from key => :a

but

```
test.a -1
```

is considered as

```
test.a(-1)
```

like some method with one argument, that's why it is showing Argument error. There is no method in "test.a" that is taking one argument

Comment: Well indeed it makes sense since elixir allows function call without parentheses.. -_- i should have thought of that ;)

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `test.a` cannot be anything, accepting parameters in Elixir (read: it cannot be a module function,) hence this is clearly a bug in Elixir parser, that should be filed. `test.a -1` should be never ever resolved as `test.a(-1)`, since the latter _is invalid syntax in Elixir_.